# ASP.NET MVC : OnResultExecuted redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm overriding [OnResultExecuted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuted?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) checking a condition: if it is true then redirect.

I'm struggling on figure out how to make redirect working. I have to launch redirect only on result executed because I have to check if the http response is 404 (if so redirect to a search page ... etc.)

Here's my code

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    [...]
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried : `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @JuanR no, because, in my case, Application_Error is not fired!  (working on Application_Error is part of the answer for that question)

Comment: Have you tried `Application_EndRequest`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it works! Please write the answer and I'll check it as correct!

Comment: @MassimoVariolo sure, i have added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    [...]
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```